# Composer error after installing

Tags: terminal, composer-php

`sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` 
from the terminal. I got this output:

```
Composer successfully installed to: /Users/kevin/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.
```

Then I tried running: `composer -h`

And it didn't work, it said command not found. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Comment: You need to move `composer.phar` inside `/usr/local/bin` if you want install composer globally, or just call `php composer.phar -h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the script said, composer is installed to `/Users/kevin/composer.phar`, which means it is only available when you are in this directory. In order to make it available everywhere, the file has to be placed inside the `/usr/local/bin` folder.

The following command will install it there directly:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.